# DAX formula to calculate bonus or income tax

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I am trying to make a measure that calculates for instance the income tax. The starting point is always an amount of money earned, lets call the starting point NetProfit.
As an example we take a NetProfit of $100K

```
Taxrate first 60k NetProfit is 40%
Taxrate remaining NetProfit is 70%
The outcome of the measure is amount of Tax
60k x 0.4 = 24k 
40k x 0.7 = 28k 
Total Tax = 52k (24k + 28k)
```

Comment: Can you show some sample data and your expected output.

Comment: To properly insert code you can paste it into the editor and click `{ }` button or surround it with triple backtick. Please refer to te formatting help on the side of the editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fact table as following

```
| Profit |
|--------|
| 40000  |
| 60000  |
| 100000 |
| 10000  |
| 61000  |
```

you can achieve the total Tax with the following measures

```
total:= SUM('fact'[Profit])

// if you want the subtotal tax with 60:40
totalTax:= 
VAR _1stTaxSlot = 60000
VAR _totalTax =
    IF (
        [total] <= _1stTaxSlot,
        [total] * 0.6,
        ( [total] - _1stTaxSlot ) * 0.4 + _1stTaxSlot * 0.6
    )
RETURN
    _totalTax

//if you want the subtotal level with summation of all calculated tax
totalTax2 :=
VAR _1stTaxSlot = 60000
VAR _totalTax2 =
    SUMX (
        'fact',
        IF (
            'fact'[Profit] <= _1stTaxSlot,
            'fact'[Profit] * 0.6,
            ( ( 'fact'[Profit] - _1stTaxSlot ) * 0.4 ) + ( _1stTaxSlot * 0.6 )
        )
    )
RETURN
    _totalTax2
```

[image: SOlution]